# PHP Form CSS & Positioning

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, forms

Thank you for taking the time to read/answer this.

First thing: [my career page](http://www.ocalaplastering.com/career.php) has a pre-made contact form that i turned into a job application. I have two layout questions:

1.) How do i get the 'checkbox' buttons to line up a little closer to each other. I tried td colspan="2" which is the case later in the form for 2 buttons (submit/reset 1 which i removed), but to no avail, "No" appears well to the right of "Yes." I'd like to have it relatively closer to "Yes."

2.) When you pull the drop down for "Experience" down, it forces the image below the form. Once you select your option, the image goes back to its place. Do i absolutely have to absolute position the graphic? Or can i add an overflow maybe to the dropdown? I can't figure it out.

[FancyForm](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/04/creative-company-bootstrap-template/) is the form i'm using.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="submit.php">
                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter]]" name="name" id="name" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['name']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="address">Address</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[a-zA-Z\d\s\-\,\#\.\+]+]" name="address" id="address" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['address']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="telephone">Telephone</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['telephone']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="email">Email</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_SESSION['post']['email']?>" /></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="citizenship">US Citizen</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="yes">Yes</td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="age">At Least 18</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="yes">Yes</td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="age" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="previousexp">Have you worked<br> with us before?</label></td>
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="previousexp" value="yes">Yes
                                  <td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="previousexp" value="no">No</td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="15%"><label for="subject">Experience</label></td>
                                  <td width="70%"><select name="subject" id="subject">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
                                    <option value="0-5">0-5 Years</option>
                                    <option value="6-10">6-10 Years</option>
                                    <option value="11-15">11-15 Years</option>
                                    <option value="16-20">16-20 Years</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                  <td width="15%" id="errOffset">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                              <td><label for="captcha"><?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =</label></td>
                              <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumber]]" name="captcha" id="captcha" /></td>
                              <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />                              
                              <?=$str?>          <img id="loading" src="img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" /></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          </form>
```

CSS:

```
#form-container{
    padding:0px;
}

td{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

h1{
    color:#777777;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

h2{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:10px; 
    text-transform:uppercase;   
    color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #484848;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

label{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Sans-serif;
}

textarea{
    color:#404040;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

td > button{
    text-indent:8px;
}
```

Thank you very much for trying to help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow:auto` from id `#wrapper` for your image problem

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can simply place both checkboxes in the same `<td></td>` to get them side-by-side. Change the code to:

```
<td width="35%"><input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="yes">Yes<input type="checkbox" name="citizen" value="no">No</td>
```

As for the image, you don't seem to have included the code pertaining to it. If you could provide the code in context around this Form so I could see how the image is being placed, it would aid in discovering why it's moving.

Comment: By doing that it stacks them diagonally right under them like this: http://i.imgur.com/ZgU7Gs8.png?1?4953

Comment: To remedy that, add a CSS class for the <td> with the checkboxes to make it float left. Something like: 
`#checkboxes td{
    float:left;
}`

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i couldn't get this to work as a class.